# Filtering out warning from system call

Tags: perl

My script runs this command which always gives three warnings. Is there a way to filter these out?

```
my $output = `cleartool mktag -view -tag test -reg win_region -host view_server1 -gpath \\\\view_server\\view_directory1\\test.vws/viewstore/view_directory1/test.vws\`
```

The warnings look something like this:

```
cleartool: warning: The global pathname "blabla" in the non-default region will not be validated
cleartool: warning: Unable to access "blabla": No such file or directory
cleartool: warning: Storage pathname "blabla" may not reside on host
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the external tool writes to `STDERR` you can tell the shell to redirect that somewhere else. The usual way to do that is to append `2> /dev/null` to the command you're running via the backticks.

If you need other warnings and errors then capture `STDERR` in a temporary file (see [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aTemp) for how to safely generate temporary files) by redirecting `2> $temp_file_name`, read that file with Perl (see [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSlurp) or [IO::All](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aAll) for easy-to-use one liners for reading files like `my @captured_stderr = read_file($temporary_file_name);`), throw away the lines to you not need with Perl's `grep` function and output the remaining lines back to `STDERR` with `print STDERR @captured_stderr`).

Comment: I would still like to see other warning or errors. This would remove everything? Thank you for your answer

Comment: I've added advice for that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that :) Thanks again!